# Separate web page title from Google search sitelink

Tags: seo, google-search-console

**NOTE: This question was previosuly marked as duplicate by someone, but it was not a duplicated of the suggested alternative post**. Moderators, please read carefully before dismissing someone's question as duplicate.

Google seems to use the Title tag as the primary source for determining sitelink titles.

However, I noticed that for some sites, the page title is not the same as the sitelink title.

For example, Airbnb has a sitelink titled 'Business Travel':

[image]

But when you enter the page the title is actually 'Corporate & Business Travel on Airbnb':

[image]

**Does anyone know how to determine the title of a sitelink, and make it different than the target page's title?**

Thanks!

*Note: The precise process of determining the sitelink title is automated, and Google is not transparent about it at the moment.

Comment: It could be determined by how that page is linked from other sources. That to me seems like a guideline on how people recognize this page & hence shown that way. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this is a duplicate question friend. Read the above lined question. It has answer for your question.

Comment: And you have asked this question many times. Please don't do it. If you read carfully above linked question and comments of https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/107858/separate-page-title-from-google-search-sitelink-title question you can get a answer. I don't know that why you can't understand answers