# Google is showing a short title in the mobile results taken from the navigation menu rather than using the page title

Tags: google-search, search-results, search

We found out that Google shows different site titles on the SERP depending on whether the search happens on mobile or desktop (see images below). We set the title tag to be "Rise above mundane tasks with colabel" as correctly shown for the desktop search. However, the mobile result picks the first item from our navigation menu – "Why colabel?".

I found two [related](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/30289/different-google-searches-return-different-titles-for-the-same-page) [issues](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/48942/google-displaying-read-more-rather-than-the-page-title-for-a-site-search) but neither of the two expands on differences between mobile and desktop. Is there a way to change that on mobile?

Mobile search result:

[image]

Desktop search result:

[image]

Comment: Does it show the same SERP on desktop and mobile? If it's the same, depends on the CMS you are using for adding SEO title. Some CMS (and plugins) allow users to manually define mobile or desktop SEO title.

Comment: Our site runs on Webflow and there is no option to set title tags separately for mobile and desktop. They are set for all views equally.